# how to set the USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON=YES environment variable to feed the PATH into os.add_dll_directory()

Tags: python, gdal

I've been running GDAL through python on anaconda for years with no problem. Today when I tried to import gdal I got this error code:

> On Windows, with Python >= 3.8, DLLs are no longer imported from the
> PATH. If gdalXXX.dll is in the PATH, then set the
> USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON=YES environment variable to feed the PATH
> into os.add_dll_directory().

I've been looking for a solution to this but can't seem to figure out how to fix this. Anybody has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

use:
`from osgeo import gdal`

instead of:
`import gdal`